# Model relationship with eloquent

Tags: orm, laravel-4, eloquent, relationship

I have the following table structure :

Artists

- id
- name
- picture

Entry

- id
- dj_id
- producer_id

dj_id and producer_id field in most cases won't be the same, but it might happen. So I've set both field to be foreign keys on the artists_id field.

So in my Entry model, I have this function :

```
public function dj()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Artist', 'id', 'dj_id');
}
```

This doesn't really work. It keeps returning the artist with id "1" even if the dj_id equals "5". Code sample :

```
 $test = Entry::find(1);
 var_dump($test->dj_id); // shows 5
 var_dump($test->dj->id); // shows 1
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out, I had to change my dj relation to

```
return $this->belongsTo('Artist', 'dj_id', 'id');
```